# NSight API, Push and Pop cpu time is incorrect

Tags: c++, profiling, nsight

I am trying to profile CPU timings with NSight.
However cpu timing ranges are totally incorrect.

If I take this very simple example eg :

```
nvtxRangePushA("Testing");
Sleep(100);
nvtxRangePop();
```

I would expect NSight to give me a CPU time of 100 ms.

Instead it reports me 0.1 ms.

Is there a way to get correct CPU timings (some extra configuration settings).

I'm using latest NSight version (2023.3.1 -> Windows)